# Running order of static code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project using .Net mvc. I have a csharp class containing both a static constructor and some static filed.

```
    private static Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    private static Class2 obj2 = new Class2();


    static Foo()
    {
       Init();
    }

   private static void Init()
   {
       obj1.DoSomething();
       obj2.DoSomething();
   }
```

This class is part of my DomainModel, and is referenced in my Controller code.  When I run the project with VS2008. It seems Init() is called before the Controller code uses obj1 and obj2. But when I deploy the code to a virtual server, Init() seems not being called at all. Is there any way to guarantee the execution order of these methods?

Comment: I think it would be better to state what you are trying to achive by doing this. I'm pretty you will find there is a better approach.

Comment: I agree this is not the best OO aproach at all. This is my FakeRepository implementation. Just want to implement the business logic without touching the real database, that's why I am using bunch of static fields here. I am still fighting to find the answer, but I am feeling that my assumptiong (that the init wasn't called) was wrong. I will let you know what I discover later.

Comment: OK- you're definitely taking the wrong approach. There are quite a few articles on how to do this without touching a real DB. The ASP.NET MVC Tutorial on LINQ to SQL briefly touches this- http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-10-cs.aspx. If you are doing it that way, you could just create another IMovieRepository. Perhaps ask another question about how to do this- it's a bit difficult to explain in a comment.

Comment: Actually, I am quite with the approach. This approach is taken from Steven Anderson's famous book, and I have used it to create dozens of repositories. So far so good. And also, I have found the problem of my code. You can see it in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you do *genuinely* reference this class (not just static methods in a derived class) then the C# specification guarantees that the static variables are initialized, then the static constructor is executed. Likewise, assuming no partial classes are involved, the C# spec guarantees that `obj1` will be initialized before `obj2`.

You would only be able to "see" `obj1` and `obj2` before `Init()` is called if you use their values in the `Class1` or `Class2` constructors (as those constructors will be called as part of initializing the static variables).

Now, it's hard to talk in more concrete terms than that without seeing the rest of your code. If you can produce a [short but complete example](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/complete.html) which demonstrates the problem, that would be easier to discuss in detail.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are right, this strange behavior of my code maybe a bug somewhere else(such as modelbinding , etc.) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm pretty shure it is called. When you use a static constructor in C#, C# applies the "beforefieldinit" attribute to your class, so the static constructor is guaranteed to be called at some point before the static members of type are used for the first time.

So, are you shure you actually use the static members? If you don't there is no guarantee the static constructor will execute.

Comment: Not quite: the compiler applies "beforefieldinit" when you *don't* have a static constructor. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/beforefieldinit.html

Comment: Oh, got that mixed up. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understand your question. assume that you want to do some action before each Action being call then "Action Filter" is your friend. See this [link](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have found my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the problem. The real problem is some funky I18n problem. When I start the application with vs2008, the parameter passed from view to my controller is encoded with GB2312, and when I deployed to a virtual server, the parameter is encoded with utf-8 with corrupted value. I have no idea how to configure the virtual server to send values in  GB2312, so I just removed the dependencies for my Chinese strings and things work fine again.
Thanks for your all wonderful answers.